# Is the commutator subgroup of a pro-$p$ group open or closed?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, group-theory

Let $G$ be a pro-$p$ group. Then, is the commutator subgroup of $G$ an open subgroup? Is it closed? Is it neither open nor closed? I know that it is a normal subgroup of $G$. Please help.

The context is:
I am trying to show that $G/[G,G]$ is a $p$-group. I know that $G$ is a pro-$p$ group iff for all open normal subgroup $N$ of $G$, $G/N$ is a $p$-group. So, I want to verify whether the commutator subgroup is open.

Answer (score 0):

The commutator subgroup is closed if $G$ is finitely generated and then $G^{ab}$ is pro $p$- group. This is proposition $1.19$ of the book 'Analytic Pro-p Groups' by Segal and Mann.

Comment: Please provide an explanation.